# If a specific string in not found in the lines of a txt file, how to make it display "record not found" in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a program which will display the criminal record on the basis of input from the user. I wrote the program this far but there is this one problem,

When I enter something wrong which is not present in the lines of text file then it should display "Record Not Found" only once instead of displaying it for each and every line.

```
search = input("Search for criminal name: ")
rec = open("test.txt", 'r')
for line in rec:
    if search.lower() in line:
        print("First Name: ", line.split('~')[0].upper(), "\nLast Name: ", line.split('~')[1].upper(), "\nAddress: ",
        line.split('~')[2].upper(), "\nPhone No. :", line.split('~')[3].upper())
    else:
        print("Record not found")
```

Now when I search for a criminal name, It displays the information of that criminal but also prints "Record Not found" for each line. How to make it display only once if the record is not found.

Comment: Is that real data?

Comment: e.g. https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Street+2,+Islamabad,+Pakistan/@33.6623918,73.048745,17z

Comment: @PeterWood Nope!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing directly, you could use a variable and break the for-loop immediately after you found something:

```
search = input("Search for criminal name: ")
rec = open("test.txt", 'r')

_result = "Record not found"

for line in rec:
    if search.lower() in line:
        _result = "".join([
            "First Name: ", 
            line.split('~')[0].upper(), 
            "\nLast Name: ", 
            line.split('~')[1].upper(), 
            "\nAddress: ",
            line.split('~')[2].upper(), 
            "\nPhone No. :", 
            line.split('~')[3].upper()
        ])
        break

print _result
```